# 7za.exe: Add files to subfolder in archive

Tags: 7-zip

```
 7za a -t7z -mmt -mx9 -y Include.7z .\Include\*
```

The above command adds the files to the 7z archive, but what if I want them in a custom subfolder?

For example `Files\ inside .7z`

Comment: Check the help and look through options: -o {OutputDir}

Comment: -o is for specifying an output folder when extracting, not a folder to add files to in an archive.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the developer himself has [answered this question](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/5856d980/) when you asked him:

> Now there is no option for that task.
>
> You can use additional "rn" (Rename) command to rename folder inside archive.

By experimenting, I found that alternatively, you can create the folder structure that you want to be added. Let your "staging area" refer to the place on your filesystem where you prepare the files/folders to be added... For your example, you could

- Create a new (empty) `Include` folder in your staging area.
- Put any new files and subfolders you want added beneath it in the archive under there.
- Add them to the archive using the same command as in the question. (The `a` command in `7za a`... means "add to archive", so it's the same command whether or not the archive exists yet.)

Using this method,

- Any files in the archive that are not in your staging area will remain intact.
- Any files/folders in the staging area, but not in the archive will be added.
- Any files in both places will be overwritten in the archive with the new one from your staging area.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a C:\deploy\TOP.ear C:\apps\temp\entidadejar\lib
```

Add the folder `lib` in `TOP.ear`, if a subfolder exists, the 7z will add the files inside the subfolder `lib`.

Comment: Was the dot (**`.`**) after `C:\apps\temp\entidadejar\lib` meant to be part of the command,  or was it just the end of the sentence?

Comment: TOP.ear can be changed to TOP.zip or TOP.7z

Comment: Was the dot (**`.`**) after `C:\apps\temp\entidadejar\lib` meant to be part of the command,  or was it just the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

The command to do this is `rn`. From https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/rename.htm:

```
7z rn <archive_name> <src_file_1> <dest_file_1> [ <src_file_2> <dest_file_2> ... ]
```